I have accidentally deleted the Default pool in Azure Devops Agent pools. How do I restore it?
I accidentally deleted the Default pool in the Azure Devops Agent pools (pipelines), I was wondering how I can restore it?  Now I am only using the Azure Pipelines.
enter image description here
I tried to search online but couldn't find any documentation on it.

You can not restore the old one, but it is fairly simple.
You can create a new pool from add pool section

Here You can select Azure Virtual Machine scale set and fill other details

Make sure to select the check box to Automatically tear down virtual machines after every use.
